# What are Splay tree, Red-black tree, AVL tree, B-tree and T-tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

What are Splay tree, Red-black tree, AVL tree, B-tree and T-tree?

I'm looking for good implementations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are all data structures used for quickly searching binary data.  Many are used by different data management systems.

They differ in their approach for storage of data.  I'd recommend reading up on each.

Splay: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree

Red-Black: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree

AVL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avl_tree

B-Tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Tree

T-Tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-tree

Answer (score 4):

The Tree Data Structure article on Wikipedia would be a good starting point for anyone wanting to learn about different tree structures.  I believe that all of the referenced structures have links on the main Tree Data Structure entry.

For implementations I would recommend looking at Cormen's [Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) text, also referenced at wikipedia.  If you want concrete implementations, you'll need to specify your desired language.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure

Answer (score 0):

Besides the online resources I would also recommend you to get a real book about algorithms. I would strongly recommend Sedgewick:

- [Algorithms in C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201350882)
- [Algorithms in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201775786)

These are great books that will teach various algorithms (trees, search, graphs, etc.).